# Typescript generics - multiple types depending on common key

Tags: typescript, generics, electron, ipc

I try to solve a problem on an electron application that uses quite a lot of IPC channels. For each channel, we have a tupel (channelName, payload, result) and the types of payload and result both depend on the channel name. One example to use the channel is like this:

```
    const result = ipcRenderer.sendSync('channel-1', {value: 'hello'})   // result could be: {name: 'world'}
```

So the plan is to find a new type definition for the method to have a checked payload type and to have typescript infer the result - both based on the channel name.

The actual solution I have is like this. It does most of the trick, but I hope for help to improve it, see below.

```
import {ipcRenderer} from 'electron'

interface HelloWorldTypes {
  payload: { value: string; };
  response: { name: string; }
}

interface RequestResponseTypes {
  'channel-1': HelloWorldTypes;
}

interface TypedIpcRenderer {
  sendSync<C extends keyof RequestResponseTypes>(
         channel: C, 
         payload: RequestResponseTypes[C]['payload']
      ): RequestResponseTypes[C]['response'];
}

let ipc: TypedIpcRenderer = ipcRenderer;
const result = ipc.sendSync('channel-1', {value: 'hello'});
```

I'm not happy with the `'response'` and `'payload'` trick, especially that I could now map the channel name to any type that does not have the `payload` and `response` attributes or has them mapped to anything other then `object`. Is there a solution to restrict the map values to certain types?

Comment: Not sure if I complete understood what you are trying to achieve. But, replacing `payload` with `somethingRandom`, throws an issue inside the IDE. This also happens if there is a mismatch between, the channel and the payload argument. Are you looking for something to restrict the type of `payload` inside `HelloWorldTypes`?

Comment: Yes, it shows an error, but at the 'wrong' place, on the `TypedIpcRenderer` and not on the type that actually breaks the contract. So if I map `'channel-2': string`, I don't see the error on the map - but that's where the developer should see it.